# warning google cloud compute instance over utilized

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

i recently installed a Bitnami Wordpress Network stack on google cloud compute.

I keep getting a warning saying that it is over utilised however, when i view cpu and disk usage statistics, i cannot see how this is possible? Both statistics are usually very low only spiking when I am administering websites (ie importing large files, backups, etc).

For exmaple as i post this message right now usage for the

Is this just a marketing ploy to get me to upgrade my instance?

What happens when we overutilise anyway? (what are the symptoms...as my wordpress network appears to me to be functioning flawlessly)

Please see images of my disk and cpu usage over the last 7 days

```
[CPU utilisation statistcs 7 days][1]
[disk operations 7 days][2]
[Network Packets statistics 7 days][3]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZa0L.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUOno.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnbHq.jpg
```

Comment: same question..

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Monitoring Agent in order to get accurate recommendations.

> If the monitoring agent is installed and running on a VM instance, the
>   CPU and memory metrics collected by the agent are automatically used
>   to compute sizing recommendations. **The agent metrics provided by the**
>   **monitoring agent give better insights into resource utilization of the**
>   **instance than the default Compute Engine metrics**. **This allows** the
>   recommendation engine to estimate resource requirements better and
>   make **more precise recommendations**.

Read: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances?hl=en_GB&_ga=2.217293398.-1509163014.1517671366#using_the_monitoring_agent_for_more_precise_recommendations

How to install the Monitoring Agent to get accurate sizing recommendations:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent

Comment: Hilal - your answer is good. However, edit your answer and put the document titles in place of the URLs. The actual URL should be part of the  link. This will make your answer easier to read.